# How can i click on allow on firefox microphone popup in protractor?

Tags: popup, protractor, alert, microphone

I want to click on Allow when firefox browser microphone popup will display. I have attached the screenshot of popup window. I have tried browser.switchTo().alert().accept() but in console i got error that **No modal dialog is currently open** in protractor. So how can i do that?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEDrb.png)

Answer (score 1):

Allow microphone is a browser alert. Only way to handle it is to use flag in your config file to bypass the alert shown as below:

For chrome it would be   '--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream'.

For firefox :

```
    FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    firefoxProfile.setPreference("media.navigator.streams.fake", true);
    FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
    firefoxOptions.setProfile(firefoxProfile);
    capabilities.merge(firefoxOptions.toCapabilities());
```